# How to make current pulses

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, pulse

I want to make current pulses; the intensity of the pulses must go up slowly during a period of time until it reaches a maximum value.

I have thought of using a microcontroller to make voltage pulses using PWM, then by using a voltage-to-current converter I could get current pulses.

I understand the meaning of PWM (changing the off-on time) but I need to know what I get as the output? I mean do I get values between 0 and 5 V?

I don't know if the whole line of thought is correct though. I appreciate any other thoughts.

Comment: Ohm's law   I = V/R

Comment: A PWM can be a solution and it also could not. It depends in many other factors, mainly, what is 'slowly'. Also, what granularity you expect. And the whole design is a big question if you don't tell some more details, i.e. current values.

Comment: I'm trying to make a nerve stimulation device, I took the idea from an already made device and I'm trying to build the circuit.... the device must deliver biphasic current pulses with a specific frequency equals 60 Hz and a fixed pulse width equals 300 microseconds... the intensity increases gradually by a step up between 30-50 microamperes till it reaches the maximum value which is 16 mA.... I have in mind how to achieve the fixed pulse width and the biphasic form... and I got the thought of PWM and the converter to achieve the increase in current pulse

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami I need to get biphasic current pulses with a specific parameters... the maximum current is 16 mA... it must goes up from 0 to 16 mA by a step up in current between 30 to 50 microA

Comment: 16mA is quite dangerous for nerver stimulation. I hope you know what your are doing

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami i took the parameters of the pulse from a device that have been approved by the FDA called "cefaly" and I'm trying to build a circuit that can match those parameters.... along with the technique and the other parameters it's not dangerous

Comment: You need to add all that information into the question, not buried in the comments. Treat 16 mA as quite dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) is a technique used by microcontrollers (such as Arduinos) which is used to generate analog output (results) by using digital means.

Digital output is either on (5 V in Arduino) or off (0 V). PWM techniques use an on-and-off pattern to simulate analog results. For this first the on state is activated for a small period of time, and then the off state is maintained.

This is repeated several times (500 or 1000 times; this can also be changed by programming in Arduino). Thus this appears as an analog effect to our eyes and we think that it is giving an output between 0 V and 5 V, but actually it is a digital signal which is on and off during a cycle (called duty cycle, and in this the proportion of on state in each cycle is shown with a percentage) and this cycle is repeated several times.

A 0% duty cycle is analog off (or CAN be called digital off too) and a 100% duty cycle is complete analog on (or CAN be called digital on too).

Study the graph below to get a better idea.

[image: PWM graph with different duty cycles]

For more information go to the Arduino website and search for PWM.

Comment: Thank you! So it doesn't gives values between 0 and 5v,  in this case the voltage to current converter will be useless to give an increase in the current, right?

Comment: The GPIO output of a microcontroller will be a binary choice of high or low voltage. You can low pass filter a discrete-voltage PWM signal to get a variable DC voltage. By doing this, you are create a voltage that is the average of the PWM signal's voltage over time. This would be considered a form of digital to analog converter.

Comment: I've been reading about what you suggested... seems like it might work this way.. I'll look more into, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

> the device must deliver biphasic current pulses with a specific frequency equals 60 Hz and a fixed pulse width equals 300 microseconds... the intensity increases gradually by a step up between 30-50 microamperes till it reaches the maximum value which is 16 mA

To my mind this requires a bit of electronic circuitry.

- You want to send a controlled current
- You want to send the signal for 300 microseconds
- The controlled current should be 60 Hertz AC (ie circa 18 full cycles makes 300 microseconds).
- The current should start and stop at zero crossing of the AC signal and contain full cycles in order to not create a DC bias. (same number of positive and negative half-cycles).
- The current should be between 0 and 16mA in steps of 30-50 microA (around 500 steps)

Suggestion is to use a PWM to control the "steps" in the signal. Some back of the envelope calculations.

- One half-cycle at 60Hz is about 8 milliseconds (ie 120Hz).
- We want a resolution of about 500 steps
- This means the PWM frequency needs to be about 500 x 120 Hz = 60kHz to reach the required resolution if the full signal is to be created in software.
- The PWM has to be low filtered  in a way that does not modify the output signal too much and does not add too much noise (less than say 10microA).
- This sounds doable but difficult

Alternative way might be to have the following components:

- A PWM from the microcontroller charges a capacitor to a selected voltage. Alternatively use a simple 12 bit DA.
- A voltage to current amplifier takes the voltage as one input.
- Another input to the amplifier is a gated 300ms 60Hz signal.
- The 60Hz can come from a fixed oscillator giving a "nice" output signal (not square).
- The 300 ms signal can come from the microcontroller
- The microcontroller has a zero crossing synch input to the 60Hz signal (to open at zero crossing and close at zero crossing after a number of full cycles to not create a net DC component)
- Takes a bit of electronics but I personally would preferr to do something like this.